# Why isn't my from....import statement working in interactive terminal?

Tags: python, bash

When I open the interactive python prompt in bash, then attempt to import HTTPServer, the following occurs:

```
>>> from http.server import HTTPServer
>>>
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from http.server import HTTPServer
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I place this in a script and run the script, it works fine with no error. It's only in the interactive prompt that it's a problem. Why could this be?

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.5 on OS-X, in Python 2.7 I get an ImportError but that's to be expected

Comment: What the @^#%....and `from http.server import *` gives no error for me...I'm so confused.

Comment: Strange to get a syntax error, do any other statements work? Eg setting a variable or printing something? What python version/OS?

Comment: Is it reproducible? It works for me in py3 as @PeterGibson says, and ImportError in py2, but syntax error means probably a typo (maybe a similar looking character)?

Comment: Oh, it's some weird bug from copy/pasting the command into the terminal. When I type it out it works fine. So it must have something to do with an invisible line break character at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was copy/pasting the line of code to the interactive terminal from a script, which I can only assume was bringing along some hidden line-break character with it. Once I typed the line of code out by hand in the terminal, the error disappeared.